# Updating ListView (in Fragment) after Dialog dismiss

Tags: android

I've read some question about this kind of problem but i can't solve it.

I've had this:

```
public class Classwork extends FragmentActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homework);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }



    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        args.putInt("posizione", position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //code for number of pages
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
         //code for return the title
    }



}


public class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //query to populate ListView
        //ListView with CustomAdapter
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
                //Start new activity DialogDeleteAddGradeCopy

            }
        });
        myDbHelper.close();
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

I've created it with the Eclipse wizard.
A DummyFragment contains a ListView, that is populated (correctly) with a SQLite query.
With a click on an item of the ListView a "dialog" (actually is an activity with a dialog style) is displayed.

Dialog:

```
public class DialogDeleteAddGradeCopy extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //retrive data form Intent for the update in the db
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //update the db
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```

}

This dialog allows the user to update (with db query) one of the values of the clicked item.
All is working fine, except the update of the Fragment. The update query is ok (db is up-to-date when the dialog is closed), but to update the Fragment i need to swipe right or left two times and turn back (in this way the fragment is re-created so all works fine).

How can i force updating/re-creating the Fragment?

Thanks in advance.

Sorry for my bad English...

Comment: Try CustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in the onResume() of your fragment

Comment: Nothing happens... onResume() is called when the dialog is dismissed (finish()) but still no updating the ListView. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when using multiple instances of `Fragment` (which I'm guessing you are based on the swipe left/swipe right comment) you don't want to update the content using an `Intent` as you would with an activity but using an `Interface`.

If the data is coming from another `Fragment` hosted by the same activity, say in a `ViewPager` or tab set up, you would set up an interface between the information sending fragment and the host activity and then call a public method to update the reciving fragment from within the host activity. The basics of [using an interface to update fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) can be found here. I don't know the specifics of your whole project but I'd look into this.

As for what's posted:

You're code is not behaving properly because `getItem` is not proper in this context. When you are updating information by passing an intent and need to retrieve a new `Bundle` of information you should use

```
 @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

You may have to set an activity flag to get this to work (for example FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) but basicly the idea is `onNewIntent` will be updated when a new intent is passed to your activity. Using `getItem` as you have it now will only update when the fragment is initially created and the args are set.